QGIS crash everytime post not saving new layer
I edited one layer but closed project without saving it. Now my project is opening but it crashes within 2 - 3 minutes' of opening. What all I can do to save my work?

Did you close your project without saving your layer edits or without saving your project, or both?  Can you open a new project and add that edited layer to it successfully?  If so run a check/fix geometry on it, and perhaps do that to all the project layers using this new project.  Then try to open your project.  Although it seems strange you have 2-3 minutes, if that prior step doesn't fix things,  you might remove that one layer, then save & close.  If that doesn't work you might open the project and export your layers to qml or qlr files to add to a new project but you'll lose layout work.
